# Set header in react API request in componentDidMount()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api, access-token

The problem I'm struggling with is I have an API with an access key and I don't know how to setup the header inside the component with that API access key. I'm using a default fetch random user API in example below but I want to know how and where should I add that header with access key?

```
import React from 'react';

export default class FetchRandomUser extends React.Component {

    async componentDidMount() {
        const url = "https://api.randomuser.me/"
        const response = await fetch(url)
        const data = await response.json();
        this.setState({ person: data.results[0], loading: false })
    }

    render() {
        return <div>
            {this.state.loading || !this.state.person ? (<div>Loading...</div>) : (<div>{this.state.person.name.first}</div>)}
        </div>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
fetch(url, {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    authorization: youKEY,
    Accept: 'application/json',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can pass your api key in url `https://randomapi.com/api/qcol88t8?key=TCGJ-8B0M-33L6-UX5Q`;`

Code

```
export default class FetchRandomUser extends React.Component {
  state = {
    loading: true,
    person: {}
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    const url = `https://randomapi.com/api/qcol88t8?key=TCGJ-8B0M-33L6-UX5Q`;
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    this.setState({ person: data.info, loading: false });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.loading || !this.state.person ? (
          <div>Loading...</div>
        ) : (
          <h2>{this.state.person.user.username}</h2>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```